# Connection from GOlang RESTAPI to mongodb failing

Tags: mongodb, rest, go

I am trying to connect to MongoDB via Go lang REST API. Trying to insert a movie. But, the connection to MongoDB is failing.

The Goland REST API boom states to write 127.0.0.1 , I tried writing both localhost and 127.0.0.1. I am trying to run this golang program from VSCODE editor and trying to connect to mongodb.

MongoDB is up and running as can be checked in services of windows, but still it fails.

### Error I am facing on VSCODE:

```
PS D:\goprojects\GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB> go mod init mgo.v2 
go: creating new go.mod: module mgo.v2
go: to add module requirements and sums:
        go mod tidy
PS D:\goprojects\GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB> go mod tidy
go: finding module for package gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson
go: finding module for package gopkg.in/mgo.v2
go: found gopkg.in/mgo.v2 in gopkg.in/mgo.v2 v2.0.0-20190816093944-a6b53ec6cb22
go: found gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson in gopkg.in/mgo.v2 v2.0.0-20190816093944-a6b53ec6cb22
go: finding module for package gopkg.in/yaml.v2
go: finding module for package gopkg.in/check.v1
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0
go: downloading gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20201130134442-10cb98267c6c
go: found gopkg.in/check.v1 in gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20201130134442-10cb98267c6c
go: found gopkg.in/yaml.v2 in gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0
go: downloading github.com/kr/pretty v0.2.1
go: downloading github.com/kr/text v0.1.0
PS D:\goprojects\GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB>
PS D:\goprojects\GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB> ^C
PS D:\goprojects\GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB>
PS D:\goprojects\GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB>
PS D:\goprojects\GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB> go run main.go
Hello world
panic: no reachable servers

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        D:/goprojects/GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB/main.go:27 +0x538
exit status 2
```

### Source Code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "log"
)

type Movie struct {
    Name      string   `bson:"name"`
    Year      string   `bson:"year"`
    Directors []string `bson:"directors"`
    Writers   []string `bson:"writers"`
    BoxOffice `bson:"boxOffice"`
}

type BoxOffice struct {
    Budget uint64 `bson:"budget"`
    Gross  uint64 `bson:"gross"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    c := session.DB("appDB").C("movidesData")
    darkNight := &Movie{
        Name:      "Dark Night",
        Year:      "2009",
        Directors: []string{"Chirstopher Nolan"},
        Writers:   []string{"Max Muler"},
        BoxOffice: BoxOffice{
            Budget: 150000,
            Gross:  1750000000,
        },
    }
    err = c.Insert(darkNight)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    result := Movie{}
    err = c.Find(bson.M{"boxOffice.budget": bson.M{"$gt": 750000}}).One(&result)
    //err = c.Find(bson.M{"boxOffice.budget": bson.M{"$gt": 150000000}}).One(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Movie Name is :", result.Name)
}
```

Comment: Fails in what way? What behavior and/or errors are you observing?

Comment: S D:\goprojects\GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB>
PS D:\goprojects\GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB> go mod init mgo.v2

Comment: When I run the below command in VSCODE, the Go in VSCODE is not able to connect to Mongodb.

Comment: PS D:\goprojects\GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB> go run main.go
Hello world
panic: no reachable servers

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        D:/goprojects/GO_RESTAPI_MONGDB/main.go:27 +0x538
exit status 2

Comment: @shubhragarg Can you please add the error in the question properly with proper formatting. For the basic info, it seems like your mongo db server is not running. Did you install mongodb? If yes then state how!

Comment: @MayukhSarkar added error at the top.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar : https://github.com/brandon-rowe/my-books/blob/master/WebDev/Building%20RESTful%20Web%20services%20with%20Go.pdf

Comment: @MayukhSarkar You can see the screenshots on go forum, https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/connection-from-golang-restapi-to-mongodb-failing-in-vscode/31916

Comment: `panic: no reachable servers` this will happen due to the application is unable to connect to mongo db. Please make sure mongo db is running and listening in `27017` port. Is your mongo is running with the docker?  As `christophberger` mentioned in the forum, the `gopkg.in/mgo.v2 is unmaintained for 6 years`, so try to use [go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/connection/) instead. As it is actively maintained by MongoDB and providing a more modern and feature-rich interface.

Comment: This is mostly due to mondb server is not running

Answer (score 1):

let me show you how I usually interact with MongoDB within Go. I put together a small example to show this off. First, let me present the code and, then, I'll walk you through all of the relevant sections.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type Movie struct {
    Name      string   `bson:"name"`
    Year      string   `bson:"year"`
    Directors []string `bson:"directors"`
    Writers   []string `bson:"writers"`
    BoxOffice `bson:"boxOffice"`
}

type BoxOffice struct {
    Budget uint64 `bson:"budget"`
    Gross  uint64 `bson:"gross"`
}

// docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mymongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mongo:latest
func main() {
    // 1. set connection up
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017")
    mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer mongoClient.Disconnect(context.Background())

    // 2. set database and collection
    appDb := mongoClient.Database("appDB")
    moviesData := appDb.Collection("moviesData")

    // 3. insert movie
    darkNight := &Movie{
        Name:      "Dark Night",
        Year:      "2009",
        Directors: []string{"Chirstopher Nolan"},
        Writers:   []string{"Max Muler"},
        BoxOffice: BoxOffice{
            Budget: 150000,
            Gross:  1750000000,
        },
    }

    // troubleshooting to clean up data
    defer func() {
        moviesData.DeleteMany(context.Background(), bson.M{})
    }()

    insertRes, err := moviesData.InsertOne(context.Background(), darkNight)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("inserted result", insertRes.InsertedID)

    // 4. fetch data
    cursor, err := moviesData.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var movieEntries []bson.M
    if err = cursor.All(context.Background(), &movieEntries); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, v := range movieEntries {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

Now, let me explain in more detail each of the sections.

##### How I run MongoDB locally

To run a MongoDB instance I used Docker. With a single command, we have a fully working instance on our machine. The command is the following one:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mymongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mongo:latest
```

##### Set the MongoDB client up

Within this part, I created a MongoDB client that points to my local instance. For sure, this approach works only if you have a MongoDB instance up and running with the provided settings. Plus, consider using a right `context` (maybe with a timeout) to avoid connections running endlessly.

##### Set the DB and the collection

This part doesn't deserve any extra explanation.

##### The insert logic

Other than the movie creation (which is the same as you provided), it's worth noting how I use the `InsertOne` method. Then, I track in the console the `ObjectId` provided back from the MongoDB instance.

> Please note that, for the sake of the demo, I deferred an invocation to the `DeleteMany` method to be sure to delete all of the documents after each run of the program. You can leave out this part if you wish.

##### The fetch logic

This part is divided up into two sections:

1. First, we create a cursor (which is supposed to be used to cycle over the result set). We left the filter empty so we got all of the documents present.
2. We invoked the `All` method on the above-defined cursor to load an empty slice of `Movie`.

Finally, we range over the slice to print each document in the console.

I hope that this example helps you understand how I work with MongoDB. If something is still unclear, just let me know and I'll update the answer, thanks!